# online classes for math masters pre reqs

Tags: soft-question, education

I'm currently getting my masters in video game development and next year want to start on my math masters. Some of the pre-reqs I need to still take are calc 3 and linear algebra, does anyone know of any online classes in the US I can take for these classes.  I have a full time job aswell and my current classes so I don't have a ton of time so an online course would work perfectly so long as it's accredited and can be transferred.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIUC offers online calculus classes:
http://netmath.uiuc.edu/

And the University of Iowa offers a linear algebra class.

I've also heard stuff about the University of Phoenix.

Comment: Thanks for the help, netmath looks great! +1